# Float inside an absolute div inside a relative inline-block div

Tags: css, css-position

hope someone can give me a hand with this, I've searched but can't find anyone with the same problem.

I'm re-jigging a menu for my website and I need these .float-columns to appear next to each other, but in this set-up they appear under each other.

```css
.main{
 display: inline-block;
 position:relative;}

.content {
    position: absolute;
}
.float-column  {
 background: #FFF000;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="content">
<div class="float-column">Column 1</div>
<div class="float-column">Column 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I can make them appear as expected by removing the position from the .content or removing the position/display from the .main, unfortunately I can't do this as it breaks the rest of the menu.

I've had limited success when specifying fixed widths for the .float-column and .content, but ideally I'd like to leave it flexible (so I can add as many columns as needed)

Is there any way around this? Am I missing something obvious?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s6jjns56/1/)

Comment: I know you said you don't want to specify widths, but giving .main a width: 100% solves this: https://jsfiddle.net/samuidavid/s6jjns56/22/

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion but it breaks the layout of the menu I'm editing. I think I'm going to have to use some set widths to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

as per your requirement, you just need to remove inline block from the main class. That will make the columns align side by side.

Comment: Alas, I can't remove the inline-block or relative position as it breaks the menu I'm editing

Comment: @ShinyHappySimon, please try to add 100% width to the main class

Comment: Thanks, that was suggested by somebody above, but again it breaks the menu I'm editing

Comment: @ShinyHappySimon, if  you can share the design or the wireframe of your website, then i can suggest a better solution